# Difficulties merging revisions with subversive

Tags: merge, branch, revision, subversive

Good morning,

Supose a developer has commited a unique revision (let's say 4582) in two different projects which are in two different branches. For example:
 Project A (branches/ProjectA/V2.0)
 Project B (branches/ProjectB/V2.1)

What we would like to do is merging this revision 4582 to other two branches in a single step (i.e. without the necessite to perform the merge separetedly), for example:
 Project A (branches/ProjectA/V2.0)  ===>  Project A (branches/ProjectA/V1.4)
 AND
 Project B (branches/ProjectB/V2.1)  ===>  Project B (branches/ProjectB/V1.3)

Anybody knows if is it possible to do this scenario in just one step using subersive?

tks,
Daniel.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think subversive is able to do this.

Even using the console client you would have to split the merge in two steps, when working directly on the repository.

If it is that important that it is in one commit, you could checkout the whole repository, do both merge steps and then commit the whole repository. But that will need much disk space, because all tags, branches, etc. are checked out.